# Java -Twitter API Access issue on websphere

Tags: java, twitter, websphere

Im trying to impliment twitter login in Java web application. Following is the code im using. Also, im using twitter4j 4.02 Library.

```
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import twitter4j.Query;
import twitter4j.QueryResult;
import twitter4j.Status;
//import twitter4j.Tweet;
import twitter4j.Twitter;
import twitter4j.TwitterException;
import twitter4j.TwitterFactory;
import twitter4j.auth.AccessToken;
import twitter4j.auth.RequestToken;
import twitter4j.conf.Configuration;
import twitter4j.conf.ConfigurationBuilder;

public class TwitterApplication {
private final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(TwitterApplication.class.getName());

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new TwitterApplication().publish();
}

private void publish(){
   String message="Twitter application using Java http://www.java-tutorial.ch/architecture/twitter-with-java-tutorial";
   try {
       //Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
       ConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
        builder.setOAuthConsumerKey("****My app ConsumerKey****");
        builder.setOAuthConsumerSecret("****My app ConsumerSecret****").setHttpConnectionTimeout(500000);           

       Configuration configuration = builder.build();
        TwitterFactory factory = new TwitterFactory(configuration);
        Twitter twitter = factory.getInstance();

       try {
           RequestToken requestToken = twitter.getOAuthRequestToken();
           AccessToken accessToken = null;
           while (null == accessToken) {
               logger.fine("Open the following URL and grant access to your account:");
               logger.fine(requestToken.getAuthorizationURL());
               try {
                       accessToken = twitter.getOAuthAccessToken(requestToken);
               } catch (TwitterException te) {
                   if (401 == te.getStatusCode()) {
                       logger.severe("Unable to get the access token.");
                   } else {
                       te.printStackTrace();
                   }
               }
           }
           logger.info("Got access token.");
           logger.info("Access token: " + accessToken.getToken());
           logger.info("Access token secret: " + accessToken.getTokenSecret());
       } catch (IllegalStateException ie) {
           // access token is already available, or consumer key/secret is not set.
           if (!twitter.getAuthorization().isEnabled()) {
               logger.severe("OAuth consumer key/secret is not set.");
               return;
           }
       }
       Status status = twitter.updateStatus(message);
       logger.info("Successfully updated the status to [" + status.getText() + "].");
   } catch (TwitterException te) {
       te.printStackTrace();
       logger.severe("Failed to get timeline: " + te.getMessage());
   } 
}
```

}

This code Works on another SERVER which has full access of internet without any proxy issues. With tomcat server.

But now when i hosted the same code on websphere.. It gives me following Error

```
com.ibm.jsse2.util.g: PKIX path building failed: java.security.cert.CertPathBuilderException: PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl could not build a valid CertPath.; internal cause is: 
java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: The certificate issued by CN=VeriSign Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G5, OU="(c) 2006 VeriSign, Inc. - For authorized use only", OU=VeriSign Trust Network, O="VeriSign, Inc.", C=US is not trusted; internal cause is: 
java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Certificate chaining error
Relevant discussions can be found on the Internet at:
http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=3cc69290 or
http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=161493db
TwitterException{exceptionCode=[3cc69290-161493db 3cc69290-161493b1 3cc69290-161493b1 3cc69290-161493b1 3cc69290-161493b1 3cc69290-161493b1], statusCode=-1, message=null, code=-1, retryAfter=-1, rateLimitStatus=null, version=4.0.2}
at twitter4j.HttpClientImpl.handleRequest(HttpClientImpl.java:178)
at twitter4j.HttpClientBase.request(HttpClientBase.java:53)
at twitter4j.HttpClientBase.post(HttpClientBase.java:82)
at twitter4j.auth.OAuthAuthorization.getOAuthRequestToken(OAuthAuthorization.java:107)
at twitter4j.auth.OAuthAuthorization.getOAuthRequestToken(OAuthAuthorization.java:92)
at twitter4j.TwitterBaseImpl.getOAuthRequestToken(TwitterBaseImpl.java:263)
at twitter4j.TwitterBaseImpl.getOAuthRequestToken(TwitterBaseImpl.java:258)
at com.ibm._jsp._test_5F_twitterapi._jspService(_test_5F_twitterapi.java:121)
at com.ibm.ws.jsp.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:98)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:831)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1443)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:790)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:443)
at com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.servlet.GenericServletWrapper.handleRequest(GenericServletWrapper.java:121)
at com.ibm.ws.jsp.webcontainerext.AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.handleRequest(AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.java:234)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:91)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:859)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1557)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:173)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:455)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewInformation(HttpInboundLink.java:384)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:272)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture$1.run(AsyncChannelFuture.java:205)
at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1527)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: com.ibm.jsse2.util.g: PKIX path building failed: java.security.cert.CertPathBuilderException: PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl could not build a valid CertPath.; internal cause is: 
java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: The certificate issued by CN=VeriSign Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G5, OU="(c) 2006 VeriSign, Inc. - For authorized use only", OU=VeriSign Trust Network, O="VeriSign, Inc.", C=US is not trusted; internal cause is: 
java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Certificate chaining error
at com.ibm.jsse2.n.a(n.java:42)
at com.ibm.jsse2.sc.a(sc.java:277)
at com.ibm.jsse2.gb.a(gb.java:354)
at com.ibm.jsse2.gb.a(gb.java:292)
at com.ibm.jsse2.hb.a(hb.java:118)
at com.ibm.jsse2.hb.a(hb.java:162)
at com.ibm.jsse2.gb.n(gb.java:262)
at com.ibm.jsse2.gb.a(gb.java:177)
at com.ibm.jsse2.sc.a(sc.java:71)
at com.ibm.jsse2.sc.g(sc.java:167)
at com.ibm.jsse2.sc.a(sc.java:357)
at com.ibm.jsse2.sc.startHandshake(sc.java:97)
at com.ibm.net.ssl.www2.protocol.https.c.afterConnect(c.java:79)
at com.ibm.net.ssl.www2.protocol.https.d.connect(d.java:8)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:827)
at com.ibm.net.ssl.www2.protocol.https.b.getOutputStream(b.java:40)
at twitter4j.HttpClientImpl.handleRequest(HttpClientImpl.java:136)
Caused by: com.ibm.jsse2.util.g: PKIX path building failed: java.security.cert.CertPathBuilderException: PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl could not build a valid CertPath.; internal cause is: 
java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: The certificate issued by CN=VeriSign Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G5, OU="(c) 2006 VeriSign, Inc. - For authorized use only", OU=VeriSign Trust Network, O="VeriSign, Inc.", C=US is not trusted; internal cause is: 
java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Certificate chaining error
at com.ibm.jsse2.util.e.b(e.java:78)
at com.ibm.jsse2.util.e.b(e.java:45)
at com.ibm.jsse2.util.d.a(d.java:12)
at com.ibm.jsse2.gc.a(gc.java:15)
at com.ibm.jsse2.gc.checkServerTrusted(gc.java:48)
at com.ibm.ws.ssl.core.WSX509TrustManager.checkServerTrusted(WSX509TrustManager.java:310)
at com.ibm.jsse2.hb.a(hb.java:116)
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertPathBuilderException: PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl could not build a valid CertPath.; internal cause is: 
java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: The certificate issued by CN=VeriSign Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G5, OU="(c) 2006 VeriSign, Inc. - For authorized use only", OU=VeriSign Trust Network, O="VeriSign, Inc.", C=US is not trusted; internal cause is: 
java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Certificate chaining error
at com.ibm.security.cert.PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl.engineBuild(PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl.java:411)
at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:258)
at com.ibm.jsse2.util.e.b(e.java:51)
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: The certificate issued by CN=VeriSign Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G5, OU="(c) 2006 VeriSign, Inc. - For authorized use only", OU=VeriSign Trust Network, O="VeriSign, Inc.", C=US is not trusted; internal cause is: 
java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Certificate chaining error
at com.ibm.security.cert.BasicChecker.<init>(BasicChecker.java:111)
at com.ibm.security.cert.PKIXCertPathValidatorImpl.engineValidate(PKIXCertPathValidatorImpl.java:176)
at com.ibm.security.cert.PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl.myValidator(PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl.java:732)
at com.ibm.security.cert.PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl.buildCertPath(PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl.java:649)
at com.ibm.security.cert.PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl.buildCertPath(PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl.java:595)
at com.ibm.security.cert.PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl.engineBuild(PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl.java:357)
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Certificate chaining error
at com.ibm.security.cert.CertPathUtil.findIssuer(CertPathUtil.java:298)
at com.ibm.security.cert.BasicChecker.<init>(BasicChecker.java:108)
```

Comment: Do you have internet access?  Are you behind a proxy?

Comment: Yes. I'm behind a proxy ! I tried the code on other server it worked. Is there any way to make this API work when im behind proxy?

Comment: now im hosting the app on websphere and getting issue mentioned in the post :(

Comment: Looks like certificate issued by CN=VeriSign Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G5, OU="(c) 2006 VeriSign, Inc. - For authorized use only", OU=VeriSign Trust Network, O="VeriSign, Inc.", C=US is not trusted. Did you add it to the WebSphere truststore?

Comment: No i havnt added any certificate.. I found certificate text on twotter website . ie. https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/ssl

They have given certifcate text like Certificate: Data: Version: 3 Serial Number: 7f:cd:88:a8:2d:77:bf:6e:11:b9:91:4d:ac:7c:b8:d3 Signature Algorithm: SHA256withRSA Issuer: C=US/O=Symantec Corporation/OU=Symantec Trust Network/CN=Symantec Class 3 Secure Server CA - G4 Validity Not Before: 2014-Jul-22 00:00:00 GMT Not After: 2018-Oct-09 23:59:59 GMT 

How do i create a certificate file from this ? So that it can be added to websphere.

Answer (score 0):

Adding certificate "VeriSign Class 3 Primary CA - G5" from following URL fixed this issue.
https://www.symantec.com/page.jsp?id=roots

Thanks a lot everyone who commented on this post to help :) :)

Comment: can you say please, how did you add it?